# Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception pdo_mysql extension is not installed

Tags: magento2, php, cli, compiler

```
ralfe@ralfe:/opt/lampp/htdocs/amboim$ bin/magento setup:di:compile
Compilation was started.
Proxies code generation... 0/7 [>---------------------------]   0% 1 sec 42.0 Mi
Proxies code generation... 1/7 [====>-----------------------]  14% 1 sec 46.0 Mi
Repositories code generation... 1/7 [====>-----------------------]  14% 1 sec 46
Repositories code generation... 2/7 [========>-------------------]  28% 6 secs 1
Service data attributes generation... 2/7 [========>-------------------]  28% 6 
Service data attributes generation... 3/7 [============>---------------]  42% 6 
Application code generator... 3/7 [============>---------------]  42% 6 secs 134
Application code generator... 4/7 [================>-----------]  57% 16 secs 15
Interceptors generation... 4/7 [================>-----------]  57% 16 secs 152.0
Interceptors generation... 5/7 [====================>-------]  71% 26 secs 170.0
Area configuration aggregation... 5/7 [====================>-------]  71% 26 sec
Area configuration aggregation... 6/7 [========================>---]  85% 37 sec
Interception cache generation... 6/7 [========================>---]  85% 37 secs
Interception cache generation... 7/7 [============================] 100% 46 secs
Interception cache generation... 7/7 [============================] 100% 46 secs 242.0 MiB

Generated code and dependency injection configuration successfully.
We're sorry, an error occurred. Try clearing the cache and code generation directories. By default, they are: var/cache, var/di, var/generation, and var/page_cache.

[Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception]           
pdo_mysql extension is not installed
```

I'm using ubuntu and Xampp as Server

[image: mangento]

Comment: Can you run  compiler with `-vvv` option  like `bin/magento setup:di:compile -vvv` and add output of `php -m`

Comment: pdo_mysql extension is not installed                   
Exception trace:
 () at /opt/lampp/htdocs/amboim/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php:328
@KAndy

Comment: php -m
[PHP Modules]
calendar
Core
ctype
date
dom
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gettext
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mcrypt
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
sockets
SPL
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
xsl
Zend OPcache
zlib
[Zend Modules]
Zend OPcache
@KAndy

Answer (score 3):

To install the missing pdo-mysql extension in Ubuntu, run

```
sudo apt-get install pdo-mysql php7.0-mysql
```

or if you run PHP 5

```
sudo apt-get install pdo-mysql php5-mysql
```

Comment: Doing this, i'm getting this error: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package pdo-mysql
I'm using ubuntu

Comment: Same issue as @Ralfe
E: Unable to locate package pdo-mysql
Guess something has changed since last year.

Comment: @Joraid later versions already have PDO installed with PHP, you only might need to enable it, see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/824485/how-to-activate-php7-0-pdo-in-16-04-lts

Comment: @FabianSchmengler yeah, guess that was the issue. It's solved now. 
First time for me to install Magento on a web environment from scratch.  As you mentioned, Install, Activate, Restart. Thank you for the link, will use it as a future reference.  Totally appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In your system is installed PDO but do not installed a driver for MySQL. Please install (or enable) PDO_Mysql extension.

Comment: I just enbale this two files, by going through the opt/lampp/etc/php.ini
But the problem still the same.(extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll)
i'm using ubuntu
@KAndy

Comment: Can you verify  that `php -m` contains `pdo_mysql` in list

Comment: No, i can't find any pdo_mysql .
What can i do to enable this?

Comment: Try run  command `php -i|grep 'Loaded Configuration File'`. It will output path to used php.ini. Try enable pdo_mysql in this file

Comment: now i'm getting this error: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_pdo_mysql.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/php_pdo_mysql.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Comment: On linux extension shild have `so` extension, 
try  write `extension=pdo_mysql.so`

Comment: Now i tried on Windows machine using WampServer.
and this is the error: Interception cache generation... 7/7 [============================] 100% 27 mins
 268.0 MiB
Generated code and dependency injection configuration successfully.
We're sorry, an error occurred. Try clearing the cache and code generation direc
tories. By default, they are: var/cache, var/di, var/generation, and var/page_ca
che.

  [Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception]
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'angoloj4_amboim'@'localhost'
   (using password: YES)

Comment: User/ password or host of mysql connection configured wrong, as say error

Comment: Everything it seems now to work properly... it was a problem with php version.

Thanks